# What is the name for a bolt hole with a slot that allows the bolt to be inserted or removed when the nut is loose?

Tags: bolting

I can't find the name for this kind of hole. It allows the release of the plate by just loosening the bolt a bit, without having to remove it completely.

Searches using "teardrop" or "hole with oblong" do not return the desired results.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would call that a 'key hole'.

Comment: Yup, everything I can find calls them "keyhole slots".